# Accessing and updating a variable across projects C#

Tags: c#, .net

I have a project having a static and non-static class. I want to access this class variable and update from another project  under same solution. How I can do this? [For both static and non-static case]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Build the first project.
- In the second project's references add a reference to the first project.
- reference the namespace you want to use in your code by `Using FirstProject.ns;`, then you can use the class you want to access.

**Note that:** the class you want to use in the second project should has at least an acces modifier `public` in order to appear in your second project.

Comment: That will add different instance of the class, right? I want to update the same static variable reference.

Comment: @mlg, This is the way you have to do to reference any class from a different project, whether it is `static` or not. If you want to reference a static class then do the same.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to "Add reference" to your project with the class in your need in your "another project" and make sure your classes you want to use from another project are marked as "public".
Then you can use these from your "another project" as usual.

Answer (score 0):

First of all your project must be `library` type. Make sure that *these* (classes defined a project) types *must* be public and it will be good practice to use namespace.

```
namespace MyCompany
{
   public class Foo {}
}
```